# SharePoint 365 is adding browsed Excel files to Version History without the user saving

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

When we click an Excel file in SharePoint 365, it displays in the browser, which is normal.
But merely viewing the file without saving created another line in the file Version History, which is not normal.

This event triggered a Power Automate flow, with undesirable results.
The flow is supposed to run only when a file is actually modified.
This problem only exists with Excel files.

The same action with Word and PPT files has no effect on the Version History.
Any idea how we can stop SP reacting as if the Excel file was modified?